# Command line maven isn't running any tests

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, testing, command-line

I have a mavenized test project set up in eclipse and I can run the tests from within eclipse, but when I try to run them from the command line (with mvn test) it runs no tests:

```
Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.997s
[INFO] Finished at: Tue Oct 29 16:58:37 GMT 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 6M/81M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

My pom.xml look like this:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>mocha</groupId>
  <artifactId>mocha</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
            <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
            <version>2.35.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>

    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.12.1</version>
      </plugin>

    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are your tests in `src/test/java` and do they have `@Test` annotations?

Comment: They are marked with @Test, but were not under /src/test/java. After rearranging things I'm getting the error "Cannot nest 'mocha/src/test/java' inside 'mocha/src'. To enable the nesting exclude 'test/' from 'mocha/src'". Not sure exactly how to do this?

Comment: Change the folder layout to the maven defaults. `src/main/java` your production java code and under `src/test/java` your unit tests. Remove the appropriate configuration from your pom and retry.

Answer (score 0):

Change your project layout to the following:

```
mocha
    src
        main
           java/com/.../MyClass.java
           resources/...
        test
           java/com/.../MyTest.java
```

Remove the `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` and allow maven to accept the defaults.

Comment: Is there anything I have to do specifically to allow maven to accept the defaults?

Comment: just remove the `<sourceDirectory>` configuration.

Answer (score 0):

maven use `*Test.java` wildcard by default. Your tests should have names with **Test** suffix.
Or u should redefine it in `maven-surefire-plugin`